# CSS - How to give space between two section blocks?

Tags: html, css

My css code for mobile-devices:

```
/***Mobile version***/
@media (max-width: 767px){

    #para2{
        float: left;
        width:35%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;   /***Doesn't work***/

    }
    #para3{
        margin-top: 50px;
        float: bottom;
        width: 35%;

    }
```

My output:

[image]

I want some space between the two blocks. As well as, I want the blocks to be aligned in the center. How do I do this? (Here `para1` and `para2` are the id names of the two sections)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if any other constraint blocking that `margin-bottom: 20px;` .
Left click on that div, and choose inspect element. On the styles block, on the filter field, insert `margin-bottom`, hopefully, you'll find two (or more) `margin-bottom` constraint.